# what this below code does ? <xsl:template match="node()[not(ancestor-or-self::n0:MarketingPermissionReplication)]">

Tags: xslt

I would need your help to understand below code. help me to explain what this xsl code does please.

```
    <xsl:template match="node()[not(ancestor-or-self::n0:MarketingPermissionReplication)]">
```

I couldn't find any similar threads in stackoverflow which explain in layman language.
thanks for your input in advance.
reg, Avinash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted does not do anything, because the "do" part is missing. All you have is the start-tag of a template that matches any node that is neither a `n0:MarketingPermissionReplication` element nor a descendant of such element.

When this template is applied to such node, it will execute the instructions included in the body of the template - which, as already stated, is missing from your question.

Comment: I was searching for answer to that piece only & ignore rest of the code. Let me paste the later part of the code below. `<xsl:template match="node()[not(ancestor-or-self::n0:MarketingPermissionReplication)]">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:template> `

Comment: I am afraid it's not possible to explain what that does without seeing the context - IOW, a [mcve]. Technically, it skips the matched node and continues the process by applying templates to its children - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#section-Processing-Model

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Let me go back to code and analyze based on your info.